# Python Mysql call fails silently (MariaDB)

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb

Trying to figure out what is happening during  Mysql Insert statement.
I have a utility I am writing and am attempting to open my database (Django database in Mysql) and add a record from another database into it.  I think I am including all the fields it needs, and If I actually cut and paste the Insert statement that gets generated - it works.
It however does not work programmatically. It doesn't seem to generate an error.  The last insert row seems to indicate success, but the actual record never gets there (I think it is rolling it back for some reason).  Just don't see what the problem is.  I successfully use the same cursor to check something else in the same database right before this, so the cursor should be good.

Below is the insert code in python.

```
create_string = """Insert INTO trackx_site_program 
                        SET air_date = '%s',
                            air_time = '%s',
                            service = '%s',
                            block_time = '%s',
                            block_time_delta = %d,
                            running_time = '%s',
                            running_time_delta = %d,
                            remaining_time = '%s',
                            remaining_time_delta = %d,
                            title = '%s',
                            locked_flag = %d,
                            deleted_flag = %d,
                            library = '%s',
                            mc = '%s',
                            producer = '%s',
                            editor = '%s',
                            remarks = '%s',
                            audit_time = '%s',
                            audit_user = 'todd' """ % (
                        air_date, air_time, service_name, block_time, block_time_delta,
                        running_time, running_time_delta, remaining_time, remaining_time_delta,
                        title, locked_flag, deleted_flag, library, mc, producer, editor,
                        remarks, audit_time)
                    print(" Create String = \n %s" % create_string)                  
                    num_rows = new_trackx_cursor.execute(create_string)
                    print ("Num_rows from execute = %s" % num_rows)
                    new_program_id = new_trackx_cursor.lastrowid
                    print("Last Row ID Inserted was %s " % new_program_id)
                    new_trackx_cursor.close()
                    sys.exit("Exiting after insert")
```

An example of the string is below:

```
 Create String = 
 Insert INTO trackx_site_program 
                        SET air_date = '2001-06-13',
                            air_time = '18:00:00',
                            service = 'TheService',
                            block_time = '0:57:00',
                            block_time_delta = 3420000000,
                            running_time = '00:00:00',
                            running_time_delta = 0,
                            remaining_time = '0:57:00',
                            remaining_time_delta = 3420000000,
                            title = 'My061301',
                            locked_flag = 1,
                            deleted_flag = 0,
                            library = 'K061301-PM',
                            mc = 'ToddS',
                            producer = 'TheProducer',
                            editor = 'theEditor',
                            remarks = 'REGULAR PROGRAM',
                            audit_time = '2001-06-13 10:55:16',
                            audit_user = 'toadyb' 
Num_rows from execute = 1
Last Row ID Inserted was 22 
Exiting after insert
```

The Actual Database Table looks like this:

```
desc tracks_site_program;
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| air_date             | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| air_time             | time(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| service              | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| block_time           | time(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| block_time_delta     | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| running_time         | time(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| running_time_delta   | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remaining_time       | time(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remaining_time_delta | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title                | varchar(190) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| locked_flag          | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| locked_expiration    | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_flag         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| library              | varchar(190) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mc                   | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| producer             | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| editor               | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remarks              | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| audit_time           | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| audit_user           | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see I print out the actual string, and if I cut and paste into a mysql session, it works just fine.

Anybody know what gives here? Is there a step I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: If you don't get an error, and the record could not be found it lools like autocommit was off. Can you enable general log in MariaDB and check what exactly was sent to the server?

Comment: Very strange, the connect happens as anonymous (instead of root), and it sets autocommit to 0 for some reason.  Is there a way to force it on Programmatically, or do I need to add a start transaction..?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why, but my connections in Python were all preceded with autocommit=0 (False), so my transaction were automatically rolling back.  I did a commit on the database connection handle after the insert, and the transaction completed successfully.